# How to brute-force keepass2 master password while knowing partially the password

Tags: brute-force-attack

I forgot my password for my password database I use with Keepass2. It's a smallish password, with 10 characters, and I mainly only forgot the first few characters (3-6). Is there a way to brute-force this with a program I compiled called JohnTheRipper, I don't know how to use it, and use it in a way that already has a few chars in and a few guidelines to follow. Help? And I also had a key file with it, does that affect everything? My OS is Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

Comment: Hashcat officially does have support for KeePass (w/ and w/o key file) and you can probably create a rule that hard-codes the characters you still know. But do still prepare for it to take some time, because KeePass _is_ hardened against such attacks. Depending on your setup it will take hours or days to find these few characters. You may also want to have a look at AWS EC2 and maybe a rent a powerful instance (GPU or compute-optimized) there to do the recovery for you.

Comment: If your question is about "how can I use tool X to do Y", then you should ask on the support forums of said product (e.g. JohnTheRipper or Hashcat) or maybe over on superuser.com .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help using a software product. This site is for questions about how cryptographic algorithms and such work.

Comment: Ok sorry about that.